# assigning a pointer a specific memory location in C

Tags: c

So I'm experimenting and I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to manually place a pointer in memory in C.

So far What I've done is created a struct and assigned a pointer to it, and now I'm trying to create another struct exactly 'x' amount of memory spaces away from the first struct. for instance, if 'x' is 50 bytes, I would want both pointers to be 50 bytes away from each other.

any help would be appreciated!

edit***
I guess I left out a key point here where I used malloc() to set aside some memory to work with. and I'm trying to stay within the boundaries of that piece of memory that I've set aside. BUT i'm trying to give precise memory locations within that set aside piece of memory, relative to the starting location.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: I agree this is an XY problem. But pointer arithmetic does exactly what you have described. So `struct mystruct *p1 = &somestruct, *p2 = p1 + 1;` will result in `p2` pointing to where you want.

Comment: @kaylum Whoops, I misread the question.

Comment: As @Schwern has pointed out my comment only shows how to do pointer assignment. It does not mean the memory pointed to is valid. You'll have to describe your context more clearly to get a better answer. In general there is no way to guarantee that memory will be allocated where you want (though there are some mechanisms such as `mmap` that can attempt to do that).

Comment: I guess I left out a key point here where I used malloc() to set aside some memory to work with. and I'm trying to stay within the boundaries of that piece of memory that I've set aside. BUT i'm trying to give precise memory locations within that set aside piece of memory, relative to the starting location.

Comment: you can't read/write to a random pointer some where 50 bytes ahead of your current location because that memory location might not belong to you, and because of byte-alignment. If you want to access some parts of memory it must be allocated by malloc or be in your current stack frame and has the proper alignment of your struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers are just numbers corresponding to a memory location. You can do math on them, but it works a bit differently than normal. It's called [pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm).

Adding 1 to a pointer moves it forward in memory not 1 byte, but the size of whatever it's pointing at. If it's a `char *` it will move 1 byte. If it's a `int *` it will move 4 or 8 bytes depending on the size of your integers. If its a 50 byte struct, it will move forward 50 bytes.

So all you need to do is add 1 to your pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct example {
    char string[50];
};

int main() {
    struct example foo; 
    struct example *bar = &foo + 1;

    printf("%p %p\n", &foo, bar);
}

$ ./test
0x7fff5897b4a0 0x7fff5897b4d2
```

...except now `bar` is pointing to unallocated memory. If you try to use it, it will be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to make two structs adjacent to each other in memory that you can actually use, make an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct example {
    char string[50];
};

int main() {
    struct example list[2];

    printf("%p %p\n", &list[0], &list[1]);
}

$ ./test
0x7fff5ba21470 0x7fff5ba214a2
```

Or if you're using heap memory...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct example {
    char string[50];
};

int main() {
    struct example *list = malloc( 2 * sizeof(struct example) );

    printf("%p %p\n", &list[0], &list[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If 'x' is 50 bytes, I would want both pointers to be 50 bytes away from each other.

You are in luck, because C has a perfect mechanism for placing pointers exactly the size of a `struct` apart. OK, not *exactly exactly*<sup>*</sup>, but close enough for most practical purposes.

You get this behavior by declaring an array of two items. They will be placed in memory apart by at least `sizeof(struct mystruct)`, depending on the alignment of the `struct` and its actual size:

```
struct mystruct { ... }; // This is your struct definition
...
struct mystruct array[2];
struct mystruct *a = &array[0];
struct mystruct *b = &array[1];
```

Now pointers `a` and `b` are apart by `sizeof(struct mystruct)`.

<sup>*</sup> [*Alignment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) becomes important when placing pointers exactly the size of the struct apart creates performance issues, or even impossible for the program to run on a given platform. For example, some platforms require placing pointers only at even addresses; if the first element of a `struct` is a pointer, and a `struct` has an odd size, then adding an extra byte at the end is required to make it possible for the program to run.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to place a pointer at a certain address, but I think there's some way to make sure two things are aligned, or a certain amount of bytes apart.

In K&R 2e, on the top of page 186:

[image: screenshot]

So I guess you can wrap your struct in a *union*, and *typedef* Align as some type with size of *n*, where *n* is the number of bytes you want them to be apart from each other.

Comment: seriously you quote K&R in this era? Esp. in an image http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Oh thank you for this reminder! I will fix that!